# Is this a UML diagram?

Tags: architecture, uml, modeling, diagram

Usually software architectures are described using some diagram like the below one (copied from [Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures).)

**1)** I don't think that this diagram belongs to any UML type, isn't it?

**2)** Does this diagram follow any kind of standard notation?  I want to learn how to draw these but I don't know its name.

[image]

Comment: Obviously (Mickeysoft) it's Powerpoint. Is it art, or can I dispose of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d say that this is a techno-marketing drawing that communicates an architecture in a way that sells. It's about how elements in a project could be grouped and organized and the dependencies between those blocks (see legend about the arrows):

- You got it right: this is not a standard UML representation
- The closest UML diagram for presenting similar information could be a [package diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/package-diagrams-overview.html):  the dotted boxes would be packages;  the rounded-boxes would be packages; the arrows would be dependencies.
- But the run-time dependencies to third-party services and data-sources, as well as the redis cache icon, suggest that it could also be about deployment of components that would be presented in UML with a [deployment diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/deployment-diagrams-overview.html).

So this diagram bears some ambiguity about what is really represented.  The UML diagrams would require greater precision, which make them less appropriate for selling a complex architecture.  This is certainly why MS used a free-style diagram.

**Edit:**

You may be interested in [this engineering blog](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-to-create-an-effective-technical-architectural-diagram_596100) about a cloud architecture that refers to [C4 modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4_model), a technique aiming to simplify visualization of complex architecture. Its [notation](https://c4model.com/#Notation) also uses dotted regions and smaller boxes to model containers (e.g. enclosing systems, and enclosed services and components). The promoters of this modelling technique claim it’s related to UML packages and components, defending UML for more detailed levels of the architecture, and that simplified diagramming facilitates architectural discussions on a [paper-board](https://www.infoq.com/articles/C4-architecture-model/).

The Microsoft diagram seems close to C4 when system boundaries are shown with dotted lines, and system internal services and components as rounded boxes and static structural relationships is visualized. However Microsoft seems to make no reference to it and seems to call “maps” this kind of [diagrams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/analyze-and-model-your-architecture?view=vs-2019)

Comment: "could be" != "are". If UML were about inpterpreting diagrams in a way we like we just could leave it away. Fomrally the diagram is not a sentence of the UML language.

Comment: @qwerty_so indeed, as the conditional tense indicates, extra caution is required because of the ambiguity. And I didn’t say it’s UML. I said it’s techno-marketing drawing, but that if I’d have to model this information in UML I’d go for packages (exact wording: “The closest UML diagram for presenting similar information could be”). The text accompanying the diagram is about structuring projects (aka sources) as far as I remember, and things like “entities”, “services” look more to architectural layers (that are usually represented with packages) than free-standing components.

Comment: @qwerty_so the intent of this answer is to help OP to relate what he/she sees to what he/she knows in order to help in the understanding what is represented. If we’d strictly answer the question, we'd just say "1)no 2)no" but it wouldn’t be very helpful ;-)

Comment: Ah, yes. This one sentence went down the wrong way. I for myself think that a real answer for the question would be way too broad ("Learn UML and you know"). So the answers are really just No and No.

Comment: @qwerty_so exactly! and the real answer to « do you know what time it it is ? » should always be either yes or no ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't think that this diagram belongs to any UML type, isn't it?

That does not follow UML notation, for instance as I know the only cases of a rectangle with dotted border are regions(interruptible, expansion) in an activity and your diagram is not at all for an activity.

> Does this diagram follow any kind of standard notation?

The more important is not to know if the *notation* looks like something from UML but to know *what* is represented.

As the title indicate that diagram shows the architecture, but with mixed types of elements, the closer possible in UML seems to be a deployment diagram, a little bit more far component diagram.

Comment: The icons can be stereotyped "somethings". UML-wise the others are actions/activities, but no components which have a distinct decoration.

Comment: @qwerty_so again from that picture the presentation must not be considered, but the text of the elements, and none of them can be compatible with an action / activity element, even the title speaking about architecture is not compatible with

Comment: Yes. See my comment to the OP above ;-)